# can't upload audio file to database

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to upload audio file to database, but nothing happens and i don't get any errors.

controller:

```
 public function store (Request $request)
{
    $this->validate(request(), [
        'title' => 'required'
        ]);

    $muzika = new Muzika;


    if ($request->hasFile('featured_muzika')) {
        $daina = $request->file('featured_muzika');


        $filename = time(). '.' .$daina->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $location = public_path('muzika/' . $filename);

        Storage::disk('local')->save($location);



        $muzika->daina = $filename;


    }

    $muzika->daina = $filename;

    $muzika->title = $request->title;

    $muzika->save();

    return redirect('/');

}
```

this is my form, at first i tried only for title, it was storing in to DB, when i added store method for file it stopped working

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'muzika.store', 'files' => true)) !!}
{{csrf_field()}}
{!! Form::label('title', 'Title:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!}
{!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

{{ Form::label('featured_muzika', 'Upload Featured mp3:')}}

{{ Form::file('featured_muzika')}}


{!! Form::submit('Post', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form:: close () !!}
```

when i press submit it only redirects. Database stays empty

Comment: What does your form look like?

Comment: nothing stored to database ? can you check ?

Comment: As another point for clarification, are you not seeing errors in the webpage? Or are there no errors appearing in your log file as well?

Comment: there are no errors in webpage and log file as well

Answer (score 1):

In laravel 5.5 you can do

```
$muzika = new Muzika();

$path = request()->file('featured_muzika')->store('/muzika');

$muzika->daina = $path;
$muzika->save();
```

make sure your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set